# linking the "C" style code in c++

Tags: c++, extern

I am trying to run C style code in C++ and my compiler is giving the following error:

> Line 5: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Second: my goal is to understand the error at "line d".

```
using namespace std;
typedef int (*pfun)(int);        // line a
int main()
{
    extern "C" void foo(pfun);   // line b
    extern "C" int g(int);       // line c 
    foo( g );                    // line d, Error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `extern "C" int x(int)` and `int x(int)` are not the same types.  (C++11, 7.5/1)

Answer (score 5):

You need to move your extern "C" lines to global scope.

```
    #include <cstdlib>

    using namespace std;

    typedef int (*pfun)(int);        // line a

    extern "C" void foo(pfun);       // line b
    extern "C" int g(int);           // line c

    int main(void)
    {
        foo( g );                    // line d, Error

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is not on line d, but with your use of a *linkage specification* (the `extern "C"`)

Under section **7.5.4**:

> A linkage-specification shall occur only in namespace scope

This means you can move your functions out into the global namespace which is quite common for C functions:

```
typedef int (*pfun)(int);    // line a
extern "C" void foo(pfun);   // line b
extern "C" int g(int);       // line c 

int main()
{
    foo(g);                  // line d
    return 0;
}
```

Or inside of a named namespace:

```
namespace c_funcs
{
    typedef int (*pfun)(int);    // line a
    extern "C" void foo(pfun);   // line b
    extern "C" int g(int);       // line c 
}

int main()
{
    c_funcs::foo(c_funcs::g);    // line d
    return 0;
}
```

... but not in *function scope*, like your code is doing.

Linkage specifications nest, so you could even do something weird like this to give `foo` and `g` "C" linkage:

```
typedef int (*pfun)(int); // line a

extern "C" int main()
{
    void foo(pfun);       // line b
    int g(int);           // line c 

    foo(g);               // line d

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain the namespace which is being applied here and also the scope. Thanks!

Comment: The namespace here is a default namespace which is created for each translation unit and it is at the file scope i guess